# What does that mean: cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, errors

I've got a theme and when I host it locally on my MAMP server I have no issues, after moving it to a web server get the following issue:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in /home/XXX/public_html/wp-content/themes/XXX/lib/inc/shortcodes.php on line 752

Firstly, I have no idea what a scalar value is, but here is the code in question.

When commenting out the code, the site works fine again, but, it obviously does something, so any help would be appreciated.

Lines 752 - 756

```
$param = WPBMap::getParam('vc_row', 'el_class');

$param ['description'] = 'If you wish to style particular content element differently, then use this field to add a class name and then refer to it in your css file.

<p><em>Predefined Classes:</em><br>

<strong>no-margin-sides</strong>&nbsp; <strong>no-margin-top</strong>&nbsp; <strong>no-margin-bottom</strong>&nbsp; <strong>margin-top-75</strong>&nbsp; <strong>margin-bottom-75</strong><br>

<strong>padding-top-50</strong>&nbsp; <strong>padding-bottom-50</strong></p>';

WPBMap::mutateParam('vc_row', $param);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic PHP syntax and the theme code is not available.

Answer (score 1):

A scalar value is something you can put on a scale: an integer or float value (`4` or `5.5`) or a string.

That means `WPBMap::getParam('vc_row', 'el_class');` doesn’t return an array, but a number or a string, so you cannot treat `$param` as an array with `$param ['description']`.

Find out why you don’t get an array.